# Dealing with nested callbacks

Tags: c++, function, c++11, callback

I ran into a case where I need to deal with the nested callbacks. See the `Thing::process` function. Second `g_thing.onAfterWalk()` callback will never get called because the parent one will destroy it as soon as it's done executing.

```
Thing g_thing;

void Thing::walk(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    if (SYSTIME() > m_walkEndTime) {
        // Still walking
        return;
    }

    auto obj = g_thing.localObject();
    auto walkDuration = obj->getWalkDurationTo(x, y);
    [..]
    m_walkEndTime = SYSTIME() + walkDuration;

    [..]

    // Walk finished. Run callback
    if (m_afterWalk) {
        m_afterWalk();
        m_afterWalk = nullptr;
    }
}

void Thing::onAfterWalk(std::function<void(void)>& callback) {
    m_afterWalk = callback;
}

void Thing::process() {
    [..]
    // Store a callback and walk
    g_thing.onAfterWalk([]() {
        // Store another callback
        // After walking to 4321, 4321 do something else.
        // My actual problem... Callback within callback
        g_thing.onAfterWalk([]() { 
            std::cout << "Walking finished.\n";
        });

        // After walking to 1234, 1234 walk to 4321, 4321
        g_thing.walk(4321, 4321);
    });
    g_thing.walk(1234, 1234);
}
```

How to deal with these kind of nested callbacks?

Should I have created a `std::stack` maybe with callbacks queue? What is the best approach?

Comment: So, after a walk, you want `walk` to be called again?

Comment: Basically I want to `walk` to another position after reaching the first one.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting the onAfterWalk callback before doing the walk? (in both cases?)

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Good point. You're right. I will change that. The question still remains the same I think.

Comment: I think that will fix your issue.  You will complete the second after-walk before the first one gets to set the callback pointer to null

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b Unfortunately not. The nested callback will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (with a few tweaks: `const` on param to `onAfterWalk`, and `std::cout.flush()` at the end).  Are you sure you're not just losing the output in stdout?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Thing;
extern Thing g_thing;

class Thing
{
  std::function<void(void)> m_afterWalk;
public:
  void walk()
  {
    if(m_afterWalk)
    {
      m_afterWalk();
      m_afterWalk = nullptr;
    }
  }

  void onAfterWalk(const std::function<void(void)>& callback)
  {
    m_afterWalk = callback;
  }

  void process()
  {
    // Store a callback and walk
    g_thing.onAfterWalk([]() {
        // Store another callback
        g_thing.onAfterWalk([]() {
            std::cout << "Walking finished.\n";
        });
        g_thing.walk();
    });
    g_thing.walk();
  }
};

Thing g_thing;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  g_thing.process();
  std::cout.flush();
}
```

Yields

```
$ g++ -pedantic -Wall -Werror test.cpp
$ ./a.out
Walking finished.
```

Comment: I think that it works for you because you run both callbacks immadiately. Try calling each one with a little bit of delay. See [how it works](https://pastebin.com/HswFzx7Y).

Comment: Nothing about time will affect this (there are no other threads).  At your new link, I see you using a few new functions such as `g_thing.localObject();` that aren't defined anywhere.  If you start any other walks within the omitted sections ([...]) then this approach will not work for sure.  I would maybe suggest pasting the whole code that has the issue, or clarifying the question you want an answer to.

Comment: Any other walks are not started. The only usages are these two shown in the question. Rest of the ommited sections simply regards updating the object position per step, thats why I skipped it. I will keep digging then since looks like I'm missing something.

Comment: Hmm. in your response to StoryTeller, you state that `walk` will not be blocking.  Can you elaborate on this in your question?  That might change my assumption w.r.t threads.

Comment: Just like in my pastebin snippet - `walk` method returns before the actual walking is finished. It does set the time along with the goal position and returns. StoryTeller implementation would require walking to be done once method returns.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Okay, so the issue is that the walk within the callback exits early, permitting the callback to be destroyed.  Make sure you update the main question with the early-exit behavior for walk, for the next people to read this.

Comment: Done. Thank you for your help attempt :-)